# spring data r2dbc @createdBy field setting

Tags: spring, spring-data-r2dbc

I've got an abstract BasicEntity class implementing Persistable.
It's purpose to set basic fields :

```
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(value = "create_time")
    private Long createTime;

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(value = "create_user")
    private String createUser;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(value = "last_modify_time")
    private Long lastModifyTime;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(value = "last_modify_user")
    private String lastModifyUser;
```

It sets

```
 spring.application.name: my_app
```

to the field lastModifyUser and it makes a timestamp for the lastModifyTime, but createTime and  createUser are nulls after saving entity. Any advice ?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.
In the entity you can indicate the annotation **@EnableR2dbcAuditing**

Or, create a configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcAuditing
class DatabaseConfig{

}
```